# React-CSP issue strict dynamic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement CSP in my react APP. While adding strict-dynamic in head tag , my app is not loading the chunk.js file because it is getting created during build time in inline script. Also i am unable to find any solution to provide nonce attribute to the chunk.js file. Can anyone please suggest how CSP works in react js application. also can any one suggest moving forward will the app is compatible with all the BROWSERS(IE,Chrome,Mozila).

Comment: Create a file named .env in your root react app directory and add the following content `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false`

Comment: I am using material-ui and cspHtmlwebpack, there is some problem in passing nonce to the material-ui styles, Can you please suggest the approach.